# how to select values greater than x in a table row

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to learn the language. I have been playing around with the Golub (1999) data contained in the multtest package from Bioconductor.

Taking the Golub data as an example, I am trying to select values above 2.4 for the gene "CCND3 Cyclin D3" (found on row 1042) among the "ALL" patients (represented by columns 1 to 27; "AML" patients are represented by columns 28 to 38). This is what I have done:

```
library(multtest); data(golub)
gol.fac <- factor(golub.cl,levels=0:1, labels= c("ALL","AML"))
x <- golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"] > 2.4
golub [1042, x]
```

The result I get is:

```
[1] 2.44562 2.76610 2.59385 1.12058
```

Why am getting the value "1.12058"? I found that "1.12058" is the last (column 38)expression value in row 1042 which belongs to an AML patient.

Can someone tell me the right way to do what I am trying to do? And also explain why I am getting the value of the AML patient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vector `x` will be a series of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values indicating where, in `golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"]` the value is greater than 2.4 but then you use it to index `x <- golub[1042, ]` (i.e. across both factors not just `AML`.

Try this:

```
golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"][x]
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it works but as I am trying to learn R and so, I was wondering if you could explain the syntax of your answer in more detail. What does [x] mean? You said "Your vector x will be a series of TRUE and FALSE values indicating where, in golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"] the value is greater than 2.4"...I know and understand this. However, you then said: "but then you use it to index x <- golub[1042, ]"...I looked at my code and I did not write "x <- golub[1042, ]" so I don't quite understand what you mean. Once again, thanks so much for replying.

Comment: When you use `gol.fac=="ALL"`, you are restricting to the `ALL` columns (I believe you have 27 of them), so `x` will only have 27 values. When you write `golub [1042, x]` you are plugging `x` into the whole row, equivalent to `golub [1042, ][x]` and since `x` only has 27 values, it will be recycled to extend across all columns, selecting some of the values from the `AML` columns. `golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"]` will restrict to the `AML` columns and `golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"][x]` will pull out the ones where `x` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, Sean...it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 7):

@seancarmody gave you a perfect answer, but I find the paradigm he used a bit less readable (this is purely subjective). Here's my attempt at showing a slightly different way.

```
golub[1042, which(golub[1042, gol.fac == "ALL"] > 2.4)]
```

Reading from inside out, we have:

- Select row 1042 and columns for which `gol.fac == "ALL"`
- Find positions of value(s) which which are greater than 2.4 (`which()` part)
- Subset `golub`'s line 1042 and take out columns where values are greater than 2.4 (outer most `[]`)

Comment: No, you don't need it. The two paradigms are equivalent (which subsets based on indices and non-which method selects based on T/F).

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your answer. I did later use which() and it worked...I did it a little different and it is not as succinct as your solution but the general idea is there. However, I still don't know why my original method did not work....especially if you say that I don't need to you which(). Let me get this right, if I had written

Comment: if I had written golub[1042, golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"]>2.4] and not used the which(), it would work too? If that is the case, then it is primarily the same as what I had originally done. Only difference is that I assigned 
golub[1042, gol.fac == "ALL"] > 2.4 to x and then ask to print the results of golub[1042,x]. I have tried golub[1042, golub[1042, gol.fac=="ALL"]>2.4] but it does not work. It still gives me the value "1.12058" in addition to the correct values "2.44562 2.76610 2.59385". And as I said, the value "1.12058" belongs to the last expression value among the AML patients.

Comment: Sorry I have to split my comments but there is a character limit. I hope you can shed some light on why I am getting this funny result when I don't use the which(). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried restarting R? You may have some stray objects that are giving you unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for replying Roman but Sean's latest reply explains why I am getting the last value "1.12058"...x is being recycled. It makes sense now.